# why doesn't any programming language provide support for bitwise addition and bitwise substraction

Tags: bit-manipulation, programming-languages

1)when there is already logic defined for bitwise addition and bitwise substraction, why doesn't any programming language(as far as i know) provide support for these operations.
2)why does they only provide support for bitwise AND, OR, Ex-or, etc operations.

Comment: What is bitwise addition anyway?

Comment: You'll need to expand on what you mean by this - "bitwise addition" and "bitwise substraction" (sic) are not commonly recognised terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitwise addition, i.e. adding each bit with the corresponding bit of the other operand with no carry between bits (alternatively, modulo 2^1), is just `xor`, available in most languages.

Bitwise subtraction makes little sense. I never heard of it and I can't find any *meaningful* definition. You'd first have to choose how to represent negative numbers, but:

- In two's complement, `~0 + 1 = 0` and `~1 + 1 = 1`, so both `0` and `1` are like 0 in that they are their own inverse. There is other weirdness too.
- Sign-magnitude leaves no bits for the magnitude, so you just have positive zero and negative zero. it's not clear to me how arithmetic should work there and whether it is useful.
- You can only assign the values positive one and zero, or the values negative one and zero, to the bits 0 and 1. If you choose the first, and write # for your operation, you have with normal wrap around `0 # 0 = 0, 0 # 1 = 1, 1 # 0, 1 # 1 = 0` which is just xor again. In the other case, `0 # 0 = 0, 0 # 1 = 1, 1 # 0 = 1, 1 # 1 = 0` which ... huh, xor again. So the only meaningful definitions are equivalent to bitwise addition.

Furthermore, Bitwise not and bitwise and/or are a complete system of Boolean operators, so whatever bitwise operation you imagine "bitwise subtraction" to be, you can implement it easily with those.

Comment: If you're going to define bitwise addition that way, then surely bitwise subtraction would be exactly the same thing?

Comment: @harold I just worked through it manually (edited in, third bullet point) and came to the same conclusion. Makes sense from a finite field perspective too.